# Iframe to show only a specific part of a website with no scroll

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to set up an iframe and want to only show a certain part of a page with no scroll but I'm having trouble getting the width height and margins right.

Webpage I want to show a certain part of:
https://stellarchain.io/address/GB3O3S72Y2D25EK2BSA7VBJB5BXIAIKJZF4WIMEIQSB53TEIOIADT76L

Here is a snippet of what I want: [Just the balance and 2,984,000,000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qevrj.jpg)

This is the code I found and tried using:

```
    <div style="border: 1px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 736px;"> 
<iframe scrolling="no" src="" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -185px; height: 859px; margin-top: -533px; width: 926px;"> 
</iframe> 
</div>
```

Any Help will be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As a way to solve your problem, you can use this code:

```css
#outerdiv 
{ 
width:200px; 
height:75px; 
overflow:hidden; 
position:relative; 
}

#innerIframe 
{ 
position:absolute; 
top:-370px; 
left:-1050px; 
width:1300px; 
height:1450px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="outerdiv"> 
<iframe src="https://stellarchain.io/address/GB3O3S72Y2D25EK2BSA7VBJB5BXIAIKJZF4WIMEIQSB53TEIOIADT76L" id="innerIframe" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
</div>
```

Comment: but Im sure, exist better solving. I dont remember how to get an HTML code from iFrame. It was somethis like this: 
`document.getElementById('IFRAME_ID').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML`
But It doesnt work with another web site

Answer (score 0):

**An alternate way is in JQuery**

if same origin policy is not making issue)

```
$('#contentDIV').load('https://stellarchain.io/address/GB3O3S72Y2D25EK2BSA7VBJB5BXIAIKJZF4WIMEIQSB53TEIOIADT76L#targetDiv');
```

*replace #targetDiv from URL with the div area you want to load in your page.*

Answer (score 0):

After a long search for this I finally found a good tutorial with a place to test!   here is the link:

https://www.3schools.in/2022/01/how-to-show-specific-part-of-website-in-iframe.html

```
<style>
 #div-id{
    border   : 2px solid blue;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 200px;
    position : relative;
    overflow : hidden;
}

 #iframe-id{
    position : absolute;
    top      : -50px;
    left     : -2px;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 200vh;
}

</style>
<div id="div-id">
 <iframe src="https://search.3schools.in/p/home.html" id="iframe-id" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```